# How to auto switch WIFI Router based on internet connectivity?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have two internet connections at my home, one from Airtel and another from FusionNet. Both ISPs are providing internet via Router. But at random times one of the link is down and devices connected to respective Router are unable to access Internet.

What I want now is a way using a device or something else, so that devices can auto connect to the router which has internet connectivity.

Any thought on the same appreciable.

Comment: Voted to close as this appears to be a shopping recommendation.  There are lots of ways of tackling this depending on your specific constraints - including routers with failover / load balancing connectivity but doing this **properly** is **hard**

Comment: Please provide a diagram of your current network (physical and logical).

Comment: Do a google search for "dual wan load balancing router"

Comment: @davidgo sounds to me like load balancing is only an extra, I think he primarily looks for failover. To that there are other solutions as well.

Comment: @albin fail over and load balancing are 2 sides of the same coin.

Comment: @davidgo granted, they are usually implemented together, but they are not "the same coin". While fail over could get away with utilizing only one connection at any given time, load balancing can't. And fail over can be implemented directly on the client load balancing can not.

Comment: @albin answer me this - how can a router detect an Internet failure/resumption beyond the router it connects to on both interfaces if it does not have connectivity on both interfaces?  Also I put to you load balancing is trivial on a client. For example just set up a route out the secondary gateway for 0.0.0.0/1 - it won't fail over, but it will balance crudely. As I said, doing it properly is hard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115230/discussion-between-albin-and-davidgo).

Comment: Hi, so far I cann't find any solution to meet your requests. But you can Specify one router to connect first by PS commands:Get-NetIPInterface &  Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 29 -InterfaceMetric 8(To set the metric of the specific NIC you want to connect first)
(The NIC will choose to resolve DNS with a low metric)

Answer (score -1):

For Windows, you need to set your Roaming Aggressiveness.

Goto-  Device Manager> Network Adapters > (your Wifi Adapter) > Properties(Right Click) > Advanced

Find **Roaming Aggressiveness** or **Roaming Sensitivity** and Set its value to anything except ***Lowest***.

> Note that this option is not available on all the Adapters. If you don't have it, then bad luck :-(

For Android,

Android is automatically setup to disconnect from the Wifi Networks without Internet. So if you have both the networks saved on the android device, android will automatically connect the one having internet.

If for some reason it refuses to work, you can-

> 1- Search Internet for solutions for your specific device model.

> 2- If you know ADB commands, you can easily check and reset the function. Again I leave it to you.

If you use any other Operating systems, I can't say anything for sure.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Sorry, for refusing your edit suggestion, I should have clicked on "accept and improve", if you require the reputation, please add another edit suggestion and let me know.

Comment: @Albin Its okay, your edit is fine.

Answer (score -2):

If you want "a device" you will need a router that can handle two internet connections (WANs) then your setup will look like this (Note: this is very general since you didn't provide enough information in your question):

```
Modem/Router ISP1 --- | Dual WAN |
                      | Router   | --- Your Network (Switches/APs/Clients/etc.)
Modem/Router ISP2 --- |          |
```

You might want to consider getting (or building) a router with load balancing, this way your performance will be better since the router will try to utilized both internet connections equally. There are tons of products/solutions (e.g. using DD-WRT router)... if you have specific question about a certain product/solution please open a new question.

If you don't want to buy another router you can add another "default route" to the "second" router to your clients. This way if the route to the first router fails, the route to the second router will be used. Note: This is not an ideal solution, please see David's comment.

Comment: This is a good answer, save for "If you don't want to buy another router you can add another "default route" to the "second" router to your clients. This way if the route to the first router fails, the route to the second router will be used." - this setup will only detect a router /cable failure, and unless its a hardware failure it will take a while to detect.

Comment: @davidgo You are right, I haven't considered this. I edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Some info for the download would be helpful so this answer can be improved, thanks!